# Where and how to unpack tar.gz?

Tags: tar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file)

I download for example flash player and eclipse.
they are in tar.gz format. where i need to unpack them? is there some directory where all software is installed?
My firefox will see flash, or i need to do something to make it work?

Comment: As @DavidOneill pointed out, you should get them from the Ubuntu Software Center. If they're tar.gz's, it probably means you have to compile them.

Comment: eclipse in the software centre is several versions old (and the last time I tried, contained bugs that have long since been fixed). To use the one you downloaded you can simply run the executable (called `eclipse` I believe) from the unpacked folder. For flash, I use the apt package (though updates have had problems from time to time).

Comment: @bruno-pereira I wouldn't call this a duplicate - Funtime has not said he's downloaded debian packages, more likely compressed executables (since they're eclipse and flash).

Answer (score 0):

Both eclipse and flash are available in the repositories.

If you use the Ubuntu Software Center program or synaptic (for older versions of Ubuntu) to install the software, it will take care of it all for you, and will make sure the software is kept up to date.  It is recommended to use them unless the software you need is unavailable.

Comment: Be aware that the eclipse in the repositories is several versions old. It may have bugs that are long fixed and not have features you want (like compatibility with more recent versions). If you donwloaded eclipse's .tar.gz from the eclipse website, you can just run the executable in it's root folder from a terminal.